# Get pointer element type in LLVM C API

Tags: llvm

I want build [LLVM load instruction](https://llvm.org/doxygen/group__LLVMCCoreInstructionBuilder.html)  in LLVM C API.

In the LLVM docs, it say `LLVMBuildLoad()` is deprecated, use `LLVMBuildLoad2()` instead.

So I use `LLVMBuildLoad2()` to build load instruction, but that require get the element type of pointer, so I see `LLVMGetElementType()` can do this.

But LLVM docs says the usage of [LLVMGetElementType](https://llvm.org/doxygen/group__LLVMCCoreTypeSequential.html#ga0b03e26a2d254530a9b5c279cdf52257) in pointer types is deprecated

`PointerType::getNonOpaquePointerElementType()` can do this, but I do not found in LLVM C API, and `LLVMBuildLoad()` is defined as

```
 LLVMValueRef LLVMBuildLoad(LLVMBuilderRef B, LLVMValueRef PointerVal,
                            const char *Name) {
   Value *V = unwrap(PointerVal);
   PointerType *Ty = cast<PointerType>(V->getType());
  
   return wrap(
       unwrap(B)->CreateLoad(Ty->getNonOpaquePointerElementType(), V, Name));
 }
```

but `LLVMBuildLoad()` is deprecated

How could I build load instruction when I only have pointer value?

Edit:

I found Segmentation fault when I use `LLVMBuildLoad()` !

but `LLVMBuildLoad2()` does not.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, After reading https://llvm.org/docs/OpaquePointers.html I understand I am using LLVM-15, and opaque pointers mode are enabled by default.

So the value of `LLVMBuildAlloca` has a `ptr` type, which is a incomplete type, cannot be dereferenced or get type by `getNonOpaquePointerElementType()`.

So `getNonOpaquePointerElementType()`(used by `LLVMBuildLoad()`) return `NULL` and segmentation fault.

after add the following code to disable opaque pointers mode

```
LLVMContextSetOpaquePointers(LLVMGetGlobalContext(), 0);
```

There are no segmentation fault in `LLVMBuildLoad()`

I think I should use opaque pointers, and keep track type of values, then call `LLVMBuildLoad2()` instead.

Also, `LLVMBuildLoad` will fail if give it a pointer to void or opaque struct ...